# Extract different rates associated with one ID

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a single loan database with a user_id, loan_id, interest_rate, loan_date and other stuff that isn't relevant here. 
How would I extract all the user_id's for those who took out at least two loans, and had the later ones at better interest rates.

```
select member_id, Annual_interest_rate, count(*)
from (select member_id, Annual_interest_rate, count(*)
from loan_book
group by member_id
having count(*)>1)
group by member_id, Annual_interest_rate
```

It shows the stuff from the subquery but with count 1 instead of count 2
Does the subquery destroy the necessary info? is there a way to write it as one query?

sample table

```
user loan air date
0001 2345 2.6 09/03
0002 1346 2.6 03/05
0003 1118 3.7 05/03
0002 6756 1.2 05/08
0003 1286 3.2 01/10
0001 2222 3.0 09/11
```

the result would be:

```
user loan air date
0002 6756 2.6 05/08
0003 1286 3.2 01/10
```

as those were the two loans that had better interest rates than their predecessors. If there are more than two then the ones that were better than one of their predeccessors should show

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: Sounds like you want `exists`

Comment: The scenario is not very clear. What if there are more than two loans then the later ones can have more or less interest rate? What exactly do you want to see? As mentioned in the previous comment, some examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that might work or at least the approach might help with some ideas.

```
SELECT LB2.*
FROM loan_book LB1 INNER JOIN loan_book LB2
ON LB1.user_id = LB2.user_id
  AND LB1.loan_id != LB2.loan_id
  AND LB1.loan_date < LB2.loan_date
  AND LB1.interest_rate > LB2.interest_rate
```

You join the table with itself so each user will have two loans in each row and then you can do the necessary comparisons and groupings from the result. Hope this helps.